# Rate of convergence of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I am having a bit of a confusion regarding convergence results.

Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz, or $f \in C^\infty$ and let $S_{N}f$ be its truncated Fourier series. In the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series,
the following is stated:

$|f(x)-S_{N}f(x)| \le K \frac{\log N}{N}$

where $K$ is *independent* of $f$. In Katznelson's "An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis", a similar result is given as an exercise (first exercise of Chapter 3), however $K$ there strongly depends on $f$ (it is the Lipschitz constant).

My question is - is there a theorem regarding an error term that decays w.r.t. $N$ that does not depend on $f$ itself?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You cannot have $K$ independent of $f$ in that inequality. If you multiply $f$ by a constant $C$, the left hand side is multiplied by $\lvert C\rvert$. If the right hand side were independent of $f$, the left hand side has to be $0$, i.e. $f$ must be a trignonometric polynomial (of "degree" at most $N$).

Comment: Of course, I will rephrase. Is there a result not involving the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: With respect to pointwise/uniform convergence, I would be surprised.

Comment: In the wikipedia quote, you were mixing parts of different paragraphs. The $K$ that does not depend on $f$ is for the formula containing the modulus of continuity, which would scale with $f$. The $K$ in the Jackson formula is not further determined. It is an unfortunate formulation at the source.